# how to get current time without using system time...?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get it through javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by  "without using system time"? What time are you referring to?

Comment: do you mean GMT time or do you want to get the time from another server?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current time from the web server, from the local machine, or by calling a web service. While that last choice is possible, it would be the slowest and least performant.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var d_names = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December");

var d = new Date();
var curr_day = d.getDay();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var sup = "";
if (curr_date == 1 || curr_date == 21 || curr_date ==31)
   {
   sup = "st";
   }
else if (curr_date == 2 || curr_date == 22)
   {
   sup = "nd";
   }
else if (curr_date == 3 || curr_date == 23)
   {
   sup = "rd";
   }
else
   {
   sup = "th";
   }
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

console.log(d_names[curr_day] + " " + curr_date + "<SUP>" 
    + sup + "</SUP> " + m_names[curr_month] + " " + curr_year);

</script>
```

This is how you get the values through javascript.  Not sure what you mean by without using system time

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/formatting_time_using_javascript.php3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    var a_p = "";
    var d = new Date();

    var curr_hour = d.getHours();

    if (curr_hour < 12)
       {
       a_p = "AM";
       }
    else
       {
       a_p = "PM";
       }
    if (curr_hour == 0)
       {
       curr_hour = 12;
       }
    if (curr_hour > 12)
       {
       curr_hour = curr_hour - 12;
       }

    var curr_min = d.getMinutes();

    document.write(curr_hour + " : " + curr_min + " " + a_p);

    //-->
    </script>
```